# Compiler error: 'expected unqualified-id before "using'''

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Here is my code:

```
    //test file
    #include <iostream>
    #include "stat.h"
    #include "frequency.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
      cout << "helo"<< endl;
      return 0;
    }
```

When I try to compile, I get:

```
    test.cc:7: error: expected unqualified-id before "using"
    test.cc:7: error: expected `,' or `;' before "using"
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in `"frequency.h"`.

Comment: It seems that the last class definition in `"frequency.h"` is missing a `;` at the end of its body.

Comment: i dont think ; are required for including in Visual Studio. Maybe @beachwood23 should provide some more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably missed the ; in the end of the header file.

It should look like this:

```
 class frequency {
      ...
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely an error in the last line of `frequency.h`.